# Moving the location of the modules folder

Tags: node.js

I have a project that is multiple node apps, each with their own `node_modules` folder:

```
root
    app 1
        node_modules
    app 2
        node_modules
    app 3
        node_modules
```

The apps are independent of each other, but do send some data back and forth using `socket.io`.

Since there are quite a few shared modules, I was wondering if it was possible to have a `node_modules` folder at the root level, that could be shared amongst the apps?

Something like this:

```
root
    node_modules
    app 1
    app 2
    app 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine since node looks in parent directories up until the root of the file system when searching for a module.

The only thing you should be careful of is module versions. If different apps depend on different module versions, you'd have to keep those copies of those modules local to the app directory so that it picks up the right module.